# Is there a single server I can use to store/manage version control for SVN/Git/Hg/etc?

Tags: svn, git, version-control, mercurial

**Is there a single server I can use to store/manage repositories which could then be accessed by the common/modern open-source (D)VCSs such as SVN, Git, Mercurial, bzr, etc and still keep a good level of compatibility with all of them?**

We have a large number of users on SVN, some on Git, and a couple using mercurial but none are using any overly advanced features at the moment, but hitting 100% support for each VCS isn't a priority. Coping with them all with one server is more important, especially if users can check in via SVN while another checks out via Git.

Comment: Do you understand how each one actually works? Mercurial requires only python .. git wants its own service, svn wants its own stuff and bzr is happy to co-exist with any or all of the above. This leads to a big "Oh, umm ... duh .." once you actually try it.

Comment: It boils down to, how did you install git .. and how did you configure your web server? Such details might help :)

Comment: The real question is: How did you get to a state where you have so many different VCS systems?  A better solution to supporting all is to standardize to one

Comment: @phsr freelancers & remote workers who are only comfortable certain VCSs.

Comment: Like Bluebird75 below, I don't really understand the question. You can run all of the services on the one machine, which seems to be what you're asking?

Comment: @PaulBiggar: we're trying to simplify the set-up so we're not managing multiple storage solutions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If your main users are git and SVN then your can simply use an SVN server. Git supports checkout of an SVN server and checking changes back into the server using git-svn. You can probably get similar functionality with the other distributed SCM tools (a quick google for it with mercurial shows there is some third-party support for such features while native support is being considered).

For now, that is probably the simplest solution - keep an SVN server and supply instructions for your users to checkout the repository with their favoured tool.

Comment: hgsubversion is the equivalient for git-svn.

Answer (score 1):

I don't understand the question. Any linux box can support subersion, git, mercurial, bazaar, CVS and more, you just have to install any linux distribution and configure each service.

Comment: SVN has its own backend server which runs on linux (or windows I believe), git & mercurial have server-side software also. Looking to use a single server to store all the different repositories to aid backup & deployment.

Comment: all of them can be used with a linux box and a sshd server. All of them.

svn has its own server software indeed, which is optional. You can configure it to work over an ssh session.

git and mercurial only need ssh + their own client being installed.

You need more server side software if you want to provide some html visualisation of the repositories, but this is not part of your question.

And even like that, hg web will trigger mercurial web server, and I believe it's as easy with git.

Answer (score 1):

I've had a good experience using [Unfuddle](http://unfuddle.com/) for hosted Git and Subversion repositories.  You can probably get support for hosting the other types of repositories at some of the larger code-hosting sites, but I'd expect it'll cost more and managing repositories using more than two different types of DVCS could be difficult in the long run.

For developers who want to use Git, but the hosted repository is SVN, you should checkout [git-svn](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-svn) (see the [chapter in Pro Git](http://progit.org/book/ch8-1.html)).

**Update:** [Codebase](http://www.codebasehq.com/) offers hosted Git, Mercurial, and Subversion.  Found them under [Git Hosting](http://git-scm.com/tools) on the official git website.

Comment: Also github offers transparent SVN access to git repositories, so those who prefer SVN clients can just use it directly.  [There are no doubt some restrictions, but it seemed to work pretty well when I tried it.]

Answer (score 0):

If you wanted to ask if there are forges / software hosting sites that support different version control systems, the answer is: yes, they are (Savannah, SourceForge, BitBucket, Assembla, Unfuddle, Codebase,...). Although I think it is one SCM per project...

Answer (score 0):

Note that SVN, git and others work in different ways and have different features. If you will settle on one solution, that solution will only have features that are common to all VCS -- probably annoying developers who chose git/svn/hg for their specific features.

You wrote in comment that "freelancers & remote workers who are only comfortable certain VCSs" -- and that's what I mean too.

There are some workarounds, like [tailor](http://wiki.darcs.net/RelatedSoftware/Tailor) or already mentioned `git-svn` and `hgsubversion`, but from my own experience they don't work very well.